# Passing in extra argument to new p5 instance

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I need to pass in an additional argument when invoking a new p5 instance in instance mode.

I want to be able to do this:

```js
var x = 50;

var sketch = function(p5){

  p5.setup = function(x){
    // Canvas setup etc
    rect(x,40,40,40)
  }
}

new p5(sketch, x)
```

Right now, it's showing as `undefined`, which leads me to believe that `new p5` can only ever take one argument. Is there a method available that allows me to pass in additional arguments to an instance, without hacking p5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, you can't just add random parameters to the `p5` object like that. Also note that the `p5` constructor and the `setup()` function are two entirely different things. You call the constructor, and the P5.js library calls the `setup()` function for you.

I'm really not sure what you're trying to do. Why don't you just get rid of the `x` parameter (which is undefined) and reference the top-level `x` variable (which is 50)?

You might be able to do something slightly goofy, like this:

```js
function defineSketch(x){

  return function(sketch){
    sketch.setup = function(){
      // Canvas setup etc
      rect(x,40,40,40)
    }
  }
}
```

And then you could do:

```
var mySketch = defineSketch(100);
new p5(mySketch);
```

That's pretty gross though.

**Edit:** You can also do this:

```
var s = function( sketch ) {

  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  sketch.draw = function() {
    sketch.background(0);
    sketch.rect(sketch.x, sketch.y, 50, 50);
  };
};

var myp5 = new p5(s);
myp5.x = 75;
myp5.y = 25;
```

This works because `sketch` is the instance of `p5` that you create. So you can add properties to the `p5` instance, which is passed into your sketch function.

Comment: Because I want to be able to do something like `new p5(sketch, 50)` OR `new p5(sketch(50))`. Essentially, I want to be able to call a new instance and pass in a custom argument.

Comment: Hey, yeah I saw it after I responded :) Your response is actually how I've pulled it off (great minds), and I agree, it's convoluted. I was just hoping there was an alternative.

Comment: @Modermo I found a (slightly weird) option. Check out my newest edit.

Comment: Neat find. I suppose that works because the you're actually assigning a property to the `myp5` object after instantiation, and `sketch.setup` is reading from that. This is from the top of my head though, I could be wrong here.

Comment: @Modermo I think it works because `sketch` is the instance of `p5` that you create. So you can add properties to the `p5` instance, which is then passed into your sketch function when the P5.js library runs.

Comment: There it is. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Modermo No problem. Thanks for the interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize @KevinWorkman's answer, you can't pass additional arguments to `new p5()` or expect `p5.setup` to have additional parameters, but you can use [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```
var x = 50;

var sketch = function(p5) {

  p5.setup = function() {
    // Canvas setup etc
    rect(x, 40, 40, 40);
  };
};

new p5(sketch);
```

The `x` variable will be still accessible in the `p5.setup` function.

If you change `x` before calling `new p5(sketch)`, new value will be used to draw the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

A way to pass data to the sketch is to add the data to the canvas wrapper element and read it in the sketch function.

```
const sketch = (s) => {
  let x;


  s.setup = () => {
    x = s._userNode.config.x;
  }
}

const element = document.querySelector('#canvas-wrapper');
element.config = {x: 50};
new p5(sketch, element);
```